# Is this a correct DH key exchange over RSA wirelessly?

Tags: rsa, wireless, diffie-hellman

*Note: I am a network researcher, but a security newbie. Hence, this post may contain wrong understanding of security including DH and RSA. If it does, please let me know it.*

I've designed a certain network protocol extension, which generates shared secret keys between two terminals, Alice and Bob. To this end, I first used a simple ECDH. (Elliptic curve parameters are negotiated wirelessly via other messages, but the messages are omitted in the following figure.)

[image]

However, I didn't consider malicious attacker, Mallory. To prevent MITM and let the both verifies that the message 3 and 4 come from the valid counterpart, not from Mallory, I adopted RSA public key signing and verification.

[image]

Note:

- Message 1 is periodically broadcasted so that anyone can capture this.
- Message 2 is sent if Alice wants to share a secret key with Bob.
- `sign(data, priv)` and `verify(data, pub)` are RSA signing and verification.
- The resultant shared secret will be used to generate another shared secret (which is used in the existing protocol) and will be  discarded immediately.

Is this a correct implementation of DH over RSA wirelessly? Or are there something that I am missing?

Comment: The second protocol still looks like the attacker will be able to MITM the protocol by sending his own keys at the RSA-Key exchange phase.